# Why are my comments not showing up, in this PHP script?

Tags: php

This follows on from my last question on the topic. I tried to post comments on a post I created on my website. The thing is, the comments are not showing up.

Here's the code:

```
    <?php
                        $getid = $_GET['id'];

                        // Get relevent comments
                        $get_comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post_comments WHERE post_id='$getid' ORDER BY id DESC");
                        $count = mysql_num_rows($get_comments);
                        if ($count != 0) {
                            while ($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_comments)) {

                                $comment_body = $comment['post_body'];
                                $posted_to = $comment['posted_to'];
                                $posted_by = $comment['posted_by'];
                                $removed = $comment['post_removed'];

                                $comments = "<b><a href='$posted_by' target='_blank'>$posted_by</a> said: <br /></b>".$comment_body."<hr /><br />";
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            // Do nothing!
                        }
                        echo "
                        <br />
                        <div class='newsFeedPost'>
                        <div class='newsFeedPostOptions'>
                        <a href='javascript:;' onClick='javascript:toggle$id()'>Show Comments</a>
                        <div style='float: left;'>
                        <a href='$added_by'><img src='$profilepic_info' height='60' /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class='posted_by'><a href='$added_by'>$added_by</a> wrote:</div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <div style='max-width: 600px; height: auto;'>
                        $body<br /><br /><br /><p />
                        </div>
                            Like &ndash; Re-Shout! &ndash; Comment
                        <br />$comments
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        ";
                        }
}
?>
```

Any ideas on why it's not showing up? Also, don't mind the MySQL code, it's for test purposes only!

I also heard that using AJAX would be a good option. How would I do that? (I'm quite new to PHP etc.)

Comment: You had thick an answer for this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379010/comments-on-posts-php

Comment: Have a look at the manual at php.net/mysql_query - this function returns `false` if there is an error. It is therefore a good idea to test this after the call e.g. `if (!$get_comments) { die(mysql_error()); }`.

Comment: "How to do AJAX" requires some research - look at "PHP AJAX example PDO" to see how to do it. There are thousands of these on the web. `:-)`

Comment: I'll look into everything some more. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try it. I used like it if I understand your code. If you need more please give us your full code.

```
    <?php
$getid = $_GET['id'];

// Get relevent comments
$get_comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post_comments WHERE post_id='$getid' ORDER BY id DESC");
$count = mysql_num_rows($get_comments);
if ($count > 0) {
while ($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_comments)) {
$comment_body = $comment['post_body'];
$posted_to = $comment['posted_to'];
$posted_by = $comment['posted_by'];
$removed = $comment['post_removed'];

    }
}
else 
{
 // Do nothing!
}
echo '
<br />
<div class="newsFeedPost">
    <div class="newsFeedPostOptions">
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="javascript:toggle'.$id.'()">Show Comments</a>
          <div style="float: left;">
          <a href="'.$added_by.'"><img src="'.$profilepic_info.'" height="60" /></a>
          </div>
               <div class="'.posted_by.'"><a href="'.$added_by.'">'.$added_by.'</a> wrote:</div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div style="max-width: 600px; height: auto;">
                    '.$body.'<br /><br /><br /><p />
                    </div>
                        Like &ndash; Re-Shout! &ndash; Comment
                    <br /><b><a href='.$posted_by.' target='_blank'>'.$posted_by.'</a> said: <br /></b>'.$comment_body.'<hr /><br />
      </div>
</div>
';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Thanks for giving it a try though!